# Doubts about orthogonal positive basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I've a doubt regarding orthogonal **positive** bases

An orthogonal basis $\mathscr{C}=(\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}, \vec{v_3})$ in $V_3$ is defined as "positive" if

$\vec{v_1} \wedge \vec{v_2} \cdot \vec{v_3}>0$

For an orthogonal **positive** basis $\mathscr{C}$ are any of these "properties" true?

$\vec{v_1}\wedge \vec{v_2} = \vec{v_3}$

Or

$\vec{v_1}\wedge \vec{v_2} =\lambda \vec{v_3}$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

Or

$\vec{v_1}\wedge \vec{v_2} =\lambda \vec{v_3}$ with $\lambda >0$

In other words if I have to determine the third vector of such basis knowing the first two, if I do $\vec{v_1}\wedge \vec{v_2} $ I get the vector $\vec{v_3}$ I was looking for, but then how can I be sure that $\vec{v_1} \wedge \vec{v_2} \cdot \vec{v_3}>0$ (i.e. the basis found is orthogonal and **positive**)?

If so,  $\vec{v_2}\wedge \vec{v_1} $ would give me a $\vec{v_3}$ that forms a orthogonal and **negative** basis with   $\vec{v_2}$ and $ \vec{v_1} $, right?

I can't actually get the difference between the two cross products, or better they are different of course but how can I understand in advice when it will give me a **positive** or a **negative** orthogonal basis?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Why don't you try testing this yourself?  Find $v_1 \wedge v_2$ and set it equal to $v_3$.  Then check whether $v_1\wedge v_2 \cdot v_3 \gt 0$.  Then you should be able to figure out whether multiplying $v_3$ by a positive or negative number makes the triple product positive or negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to differentiate [orthogonal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_basis) $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ for which you have $e_i \cdot e_j=0$ for $i \neq j$ from [orthonormal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis) which are orthogonal basis with the additional requirement $e_1 \cdot e_1 = e_2 \cdot e_2 = e_3 \cdot e_3 =1$.

The last important notion in the background of your post is [orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_%28vector_space%29) of a vector space.

As you said a basis $\mathscr{C}=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ is said to be **positive** if $(e_1 \wedge e_2) \cdot e_3 >0$.

Now what can happen?

- You always have $e_1 \wedge e_2 = \lambda e_3$ with $\lambda >0$ if $\mathscr{C}$ is a **positive** basis.
- If $e_1,e_2$ are unit vectors (in the basis $\mathscr{C}$), you'll have $e_3 = e_1 \wedge e_2$. This might not be the case if those vectors are not unit vectors.
- If $e_3= e_1 \wedge e_2$, you'll always have $(e_1 \wedge e_2) \cdot e_3 = (e_1 \wedge e_2) \cdot (e_1 \wedge e_2) >0$.
- And indeed $(e_1,e_2,e_2 \wedge e_1)$ is a **negative** basis.

Comment: @Bye_World Thanks for the corrections!